# Updating domain class in grails

Tags: sql-server, grails, grails-orm

I want to add new fields to a domain class so that it updates the generated table's attributes set. I have a domain class like this,,

```
Class Book {
String name
  static constraints = {
   name nullable:false
  }

 String toString() {
        return name
 }
}
```

The GORM generated includes name along with id and version. Now I want to add ISBN to Book domain class as following

```
 Class Book {
    String name
    String ISBN
      static constraints = {
       name nullable:false
       ISBN nullable:true
      }

     String toString() {
            return name
     }
    }
```

I don't want to use `create-drop` in `DataSource.groovy` because it will delete all my previous data. My `DataSource.groovy` looks like this,,

```
 dataSource {
         dbCreate = "update"
         url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/databaseName"
         username = "username"
         password = "password"
  }
```

I want GORM to add ISBN field to book table. But its not happening. Where am I wrong ?

I am using sql server 2008 and grails version 2.1.1

Answer (score 3):

```
dataSource {
     dbCreate = "update"
}
```

should do the trick.  It updates you db without dropping the tables

Comment: is this field defined for each environment? Check also the start-up log, there should be some warnings in case of failed schema changes

Answer (score 2):

you will need to crate this field in sql server by hand it use to be a easy task in sqlserver because all its tools, and you should take a look to [grails database migration plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/database-migration) documentation. It should be already installed in your grails version